# In a group of $27$ people, at least how many people will celebrate their birthday on the same day of the week?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

:) I just wanted to ask something about the birthday problem probability. I tried to solve it, but I really really don't get the correct answer. I don't know why, so I hope you can help me with this :D thank you.

Here's the question:

> In a group of $27$ people, at least how many people will celebrate their birthday on the same day of the week?

The answer is $4$.

Comment: This is a [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) problem.

Comment: Do you know about the pigeonhole principle?

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved using the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). Specifically, its generalised form.

The pigeonhole principle states that if $n$ items are placed into $m$ containers with $n>m$, then there is at least one container that contains more than one item. This can be generalised to the statement that there is at least one container that contains at least $\lceil \frac{n}{m} \rceil$ items. By the way, $\lceil x \rceil$ means ‘the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$’.

The answer to the question ‘how many people will celebrate their birthday on the same day of the week?’ is really that we don’t know. It could be all of them, since all of the people could have their birthday on Monday, for example. So the maximum number of people who share their day of the week is 27. But what is really useful to know is the minimum number of people—how many people can we guarantee will share their birthday? According to our generalised pigeonhole principle, if we consider a day of the week to be a container and a person an item, $\lceil \frac{27}{7} \rceil = 4$ people.

Intuitively, we can first distribute $7$ people equally between the days of the week so that we have $20$ people left. We can then do this twice more so that we have $6$ people left. Since we did this process $3$ times, each day has 3 people allocated to it. When we distribute the final $6$ people, we must at some point have a day of the week shared by $4$ people. Since we distributed the people equally in an attempt to minimise the number in each day of the week, this is the minimum.

Comment: Actually, $\lceil x \rceil$ means the smallest integer greater than *or equal to* $x$, so you should replace more than with at least.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry, you’re exactly right. My clumsy mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, 
if you divide 27 by 7 you get 
27/7=3.8
meaning that if you try to spread the people across the weekdays as good as you can, each day will get 3.8 birthdays on average.
but because a birthday is a binary state (yes or no), this means that some weekdays will have 3 birthdays and some will have 4.
but not all of the weekdays will have 3, that will conflict with the 3.8 division result, so at least one weekday will have 4 days.
i think that the term "at least" is misleading... there is always the possibility that all the group have birthday on Sunday (ex) and all the other days have 0 birthdays.